# How to write all requests to files?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

Imagine you have the following list:

```
listfiles =
['https://yourubl.nl/wp-content/uploads/elementor/forms/60916b7e4f600.pdf', 'https://yourubl.nl/wp-content/uploads/elementor/forms/60916d04e0d70.pdf', 'https://yourubl.nl/wp-content/uploads/elementor/forms/60917c5a5c95f.pdf']
# here we are importing the library
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
  
# making the request
listfiles = []
for url in url_list:
    response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('c101838', 'HQSRynw9'))
    listfiles.append(response)

print(listfiles)

for files in listfiles:
    for kvk in kvk_list:
        with open(kvk + '.pdf', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(files.content)
```

Now I want to write each of the responses to a pdf file.

```
kvk_list = ['88888888', '9999999', '4444444']

url_list = [<Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, <Response [200]>]
```

However, I'm only getting the last pdf file in all three outputs....

How is this possible?

Please help!

Comment: What is `kvk_list` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely a list of company registration numbers, I've added it in the description

Comment: It's also OK to autoincrement the file names

Comment: What is "url_list"? I think you meant to assign the first array of urls to this variable

Comment: @Max Do you want to write three PDFs? `88888888.pdf`, `9999999.pdf` and `4444444.pdf` ?

Comment: Yes @AndrejKesely, however the contents all equal the last pdf of url_list

Answer (score 1):

Use a `zip()` function to *tie* the `kvk_list` and `listfiles` together:

```py
for kvk, files in zip(kvk_list, listfiles):
    with open(kvk + '.pdf', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(files.content)
```

Comment: Thank you!! This did the trick. How come this happened? The for loop of the first one iterated to the last causing the output to only be the last file?

Comment: @Max Yes, you've rewritten all "kvk" PDFs with response from `listfiles` and at the end you have only files from the last response.